# Dragging and Dropping a button from one Linear Layout to another Linear Layout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have a linear linear layout with 10 buttons in it. I need to drag these buttons and add it into another linear layout(Horizontal) in the order they are dropped. Please help me in doing this?

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) might help if you're talking about programmatic way of doing it. If you're talking about Eclipse IDE and building the UI stuff, I don't think it's possible..

Comment: Yes I want to do it at runtime. How can I do it programmatically?

Comment: I've already provided you the link to start with. Click on the first word - "This" in my previous comment..

Comment: OnDragListener works for API level 11 and higher. I am using API level 8.

Comment: You hadn't mentioned about your API level in the question.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some suggestions on how to do drag-drop in apps running on API level 8 up and beyond. I studied the source code for the Android Launcher module and learned about the drag-drop framework they put in place for that. I have found that is a good foundation on which to build. I have written up the details of the key classes (DragSource, DropTarget, DragLayer, DragController) in a series of articles on my blog. A solution is too long to post here, so I refer you to those notes:

(a) [Moving Views In Android - Part 2, Drag and Drop](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) - this describes the basic framework and includes a demo app. Since I was primarily concerned with learning about drag-drop, I used the now deprecated AbsoluteLayout class. The follow-on to this one (Part 3) is worth looking at too because it develops further the notion of DropTarget.

(b) [Drag-Drop for an Android GridView](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/) - a demo app that shows how to use the drag-drop framework for grid views. Even better, it illustrates how to get by without AbsoluteLayout. In this case, the DragLayer and other classes know more about the kind of layouts they are working with.

The demo apps illustrate images and text views being dragged. The underlying code is perfectly general: any view can be dragged. A problem you will face with dragging buttons is making sure that the start of a drag operation will not be confused with the normal click handling that buttons do. Consider using a long click to initiate a drag sequence.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your great tutorial on Drag and Drop.

Comment: @Bill Lahti..I was struggling for a while. This helped me a lot. Thanks Bud