# Drag and drop Android 2.2

Tags: android, listview, gridview, drag-and-drop, android-view

I must create an android app that load images from sqlite db and show in the tablet screen.
I would realize the drag and drop so you can insert, delete and move all the images into your screen simulating the desktop computer screen :)
So, i know that there is a drag and drop class but this works with at least API level 11.
My question is: there is some example, tutorial or someone can explain me how i can realize the drag and drop with android API level 8?
Thanks in advance.
Marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by implementing OnTouchListener and overriding 
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) 
check this link 
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

or you can use 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html   requires API 11 :(

Comment: is a good example but i need an example where i can move only one item per time... So i must recognize the icon that is pressed and drag and drop only it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question on Stack Overflow related to drag-drop. I provided links to some tutorials I wrote that work with API 8 and above. See [Dragging and Dropping a button from one Linear Layout to another Linear Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661536/dragging-and-dropping-a-button-from-one-linear-layout-to-another-linear-layout/9683018#9683018).

Answer (score 0):

[How to implement Drag and Drop in android 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306243/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-android-2-2/14491467#14491467)

There is my DragDropManager.class you could see that is possible. In this lib you can drag anything because it make visual copy of object so you see what you dragging. Also I use floating object PopupWindow so you can drag thing right where they are without changing your layouts.

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
            {

                try
                {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    for(int i=firstVisibleItem;i<(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount);i++)
                    {
                        //view.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
                        view.getChildAt(i).setOnLongClickListener(onLongClickListener);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Err");
                }

            }
        });
```

---

```
private OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        DragDropManager.getInstance().startDragging(v, "example");
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Drag working after scroll view. and on LongClick on item. I dont have time to make better solution